# loop through two list and extend one list by a value in the other list

Tags: python, list, loops, append, extend

I want to extend a list in lists by the value of another list:

```
list1 = [['a', 'a'], ['b','b'], ['c','c']]
list2 = [1,2,3]
```

I would like this:

```
list3 = [['a','a',1], ['b','b',2], ['c','c',3]]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [x + [y] for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
[['a', 'a', 1], ['b', 'b', 2], ['c', 'c', 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[x+[y] for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]
```

zip(list1,list2) will give you a list of tuple pairs:

```
[(['a', 'a'], 1), (['b', 'b'], 2), (['c', 'c'], 3)]
```

The rest is a list comprehension. It takes each of those tuples and concatenates the zeroth element with the first element. All of these are then returned as a list.